# Implementing Desktop Screenshare using red5 server

Tags: java, video-streaming, jnlp, red5, screensharing

I'm trying to setup a local red5 streaming server to stream my desktop screen to multiple devices with no luck. the setup will eventually look like this.

mylaptop screen (live stream)=> red5 server <= client devices pulling the live stream

note: red5 server is ubuntu based, client devices will eventually be android tablets but any device will do just fine for now

This is what I have so far:

1) Installed red5-server and all of its dependencies using `apt-get install red5-server`

2) Downloaded red5-screenshare applet from http://code.google.com/p/red5-screenshare/
   and followed all the steps there

3) After I start my screensharing, visiting the client link  `http://[my_red5_server:5080]/screenshare/screenviewer.html` produces `error #2032`
chrome developer tools says

`GET http://my_red5_server:5080/screenshare/textLayout_1.1.0.604.swz 404 Not Found`

4) so I downloaded the textLayout file from adobe, placed it into the screenshare folder but I still get the same 404 not found error

Is my setup wrong? I'm not sure how to debug this since there's very few documentation on the matter and I reeeeally dont want to write my own java app and reinvent the wheel

Also if any of you happy hackers have found a different solution to locally screenshare I'm all ears

Thank you for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 2):

The error your getting is because the flex "swz" files cannot be downloaded from Adobe. This was happening to us at work this week and we solved it by finding the offending files via google and placing them on our server. Download the swz files and place them in the same directory as your swf file.